# Active Directory aliases

Tags: c#, active-directory

My organization uses Active Directory. And for internal communication we use `alias@organization.com` addresses.

I'm looking for an API which allows me to resolve 'aliases' like :

`jonvu@org.com` is email, `jonvu` is the alias and so I want to find the name of the contact which would look like :

```
John Von Neumann.
```

PS: API in C++/C/C#

Thanks for any help.

Cheers
-B

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user - this searches for a variety of name-related attributes
// maybe that also finds your "alias" - depending on where in AD this is stored..
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this is failing. I think the problem is that the accounts are placed on some other DC which it is resolving for the domain I am currently in, its not able to access outside my current domain, for.eg. if the resource is located at company's american domain i.e. america.org.com, I being in India, would default to a look up within india.org.com, as a result this fails. Now the trouble is, how do I force the PrincipalContext to fetch at the corp root level, instead of my "current" domain ?

Comment: Fixed it, PrincipalContext constructor allows me to override the default DC store for lookup, works perfectly now : )

Answer (score 0):

Hello you find here article about differents API : COM or .Net

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/AccessingtheActiveDirectoryfromMicrosoftNET04172007154931PM/AccessingtheActiveDirectoryfromMicrosoftNET.aspx

For my case i used `DirectorySearcher` in `System.DirectoryServices` namespace